# how to call different function based on condition with different button name? its angular related problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, conditional-rendering

```
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary ms-4" (click)="update()">Save</button>

<button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary ms-4" (click)="create()">Add</button>
```

I want to render buttons based on condition. in my form update should be called when I am editing and create should be called when I am creating also the name on button changes with save and add button based on this conditions.

Note: when calling the `update` function, the data is inside the form i.e. `modaldata.id`, but when calling `create`, no data is inside the form.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ngIf` for the conditional rendering

```
<button type="button" *ngIf="isUpdateCondition"  class="btn btn-primary ms-4" (click)="update()">Save</button>

<button type="button" *ngIf="isCreateCondition"  class="btn btn-primary ms-4" (click)="create()">Add</button>
```

> when calling update function data is inside the form i.e; modaldata.id but when calling create no data is inside the form.

For the field which you want to pass has to be handled in the respective handler functions(update/create)

Answer (score 0):

Dear there are lot of ways to achieve that

- one way of is by adding if conditions (can be set in multiways)
- Other could be using routes by adding post fix to routes like /update or /create

Comment: Read this: [answer]